# Trying to create a python program with py2neo (2.0.9) that creates a Neo4j graph, but the server refuses to let me connect to it

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

My code/the manual's code

> from py2neo import Graph, Node
>
> graph = Graph()
>
> alice = Node("Person",name="Alice")
>
> graph.create(alice)

And the error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py",
>   line 322, in submit
>       response = send()   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py",
>   line 317, in send
>       http.request(xstr(method), xstr(uri.absolute_path_reference), body, headers)   File
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 1229, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 1275, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 1224, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 1016, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 956, in send
>       self.connect()   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py",
>   line 80, in connect
>       self.source_address)   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py",
>   line 727, in create_connection
>       raise err   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py",
>   line 716, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ex.py", line 4, in 
>       graph.create(alice)   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py",
>   line 706, in create
>       statement = CreateStatement(self)   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/create.py",
>   line 44, in **init**
>       self.supports_node_labels = self.graph.supports_node_labels   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py",
>   line 1080, in supports_node_labels
>       return self.neo4j_version >= (2, 0)   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py",
>   line 958, in neo4j_version
>       return version_tuple(self.resource.metadata["neo4j_version"])   File
>   "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py",
>   line 213, in metadata
>       self.get()   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/core.py",
>   line 258, in get
>       response = self.__base.get(headers=headers, redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)   File
>   "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py",
>   line 966, in get
>       return self.__get_or_head("GET", if_modified_since, headers, redirect_limit, **kwargs)   File
>   "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py",
>   line 943, in __get_or_head
>       return rq.submit(redirect_limit=redirect_limit, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py",
>   line 433, in submit
>       http, rs = submit(self.method, uri, self.body, self.headers)   File
>   "/Users/ben/Documents/CompSci/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py",
>   line 362, in submit
>       raise SocketError(code, description, host_port=uri.host_port) py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

myserver - localhost or server in which neo4j is running

auth=("username", "password")

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node
graph = Graph("bolt://<myserver>:7687", auth=("neo4j", "psswrd"))
tx = graph.begin()
alice = Node("Person", name="Alice")
tx.create(alice)
tx.commit()
```